# HTML/CSS Element Positioning (html schedule/calendar)

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an html and css based schedule/calendar, but I've ran into a few problems.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpfg5/

What I'm wanting is to be able to have any of the "blocks", such as "Block-A" or "Block-B", be stretched out. The gray bars behind the blocks are just grids.

Also, I'm not sure what the best way is to make the gray grids line up with the times at the top?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="schedule_row">
    <div class="day">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        6 AM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        7 AM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        8 AM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        9 AM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        10 AM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        11 AM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        12 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        1 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        2 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        3 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        4 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        5 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        6 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        7 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        8 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        9 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        10 PM
    </div>
    <div class="timehead">
        11 PM
    </div>
</div>
<div id="schedule_row" style="margin-top: -20px;">
    <div class="day daylist">
        <span class="weekday">Today</span>
        <span class="date">Oct 19, 2012</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeslot first"><div class="requestblock blue 2hr">Block A</div></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"><div class="requestblock red 2hr">Block B</div></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
</div>
<div id="schedule_row">
    <div class="day daylist">
        <span class="weekday">Saturday</span>
        <span class="date">Oct 20, 2012</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeslot first"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
    <div class="timeslot"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#schedule_row {
    min-height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.day {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6D645D;
    float: left;
}
.daylist {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.timeslot {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background: #E1E1E1;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80px;
    width: 20px;
}
.timehead {
    color: #6D645D;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 13px;
}
span.weekday {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span.date {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #A8A7A5;
    display: block;
}
.requestblock {
    background: #777777;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    margin-top: 30px;
     -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.blue {
    background: #3A87AD;
}
.red {
    background: #B94A48;
}
.first {
    margin-left:5px;
}
.1hr {
    min-width: 300px !important;
}
.2hr {
    min-width: 100px !important;
}​
```

Comment: "What I'm wanting is to be able to have any of the "blocks", such as "Block-A" or "Block-B", be stretched out. The gray bars behind the blocks are just grids." - If what, or when what? What is the trigger or rule that dictates these or any other box should be wider? Your intention is unclear. Also, timetables are tabled data - data existing in both columns and rows. If you want the column header to resize with the column content, you use a table. That's how we did it, that's how the $50k software we bought to do the same did it. (http://allocateplus.com.au/students.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want block a and block b to horizontally fill the grey bar. I did this by removing the padding on `.timeslot` and increasing the width to 36px (8px + 8px + original width). You can see this here:

if you are referring the the height of each block, you would have to remove the `margin-top` on `.requestblock` and declare `height: 80px` on it.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. What I'm after is to be able to have either block a or b stretch over the gray bars (using the .1hr, .2hr classes). I want the gray bars to remain the same width and height. I just want to be able to stretch the a or b blocks over the gray bars.